# How to transform a string by selectively adding or removing characters using javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I am struggling with the following problem:

Lets say I have a **string** `'foo.bar.baz'`. I want to transform it to `foo[bar][baz]`

Is there a neat way to do this using JavaScript?

Comment: Can you post your attempt so far and a demo to reproduce the issue you are having?

Comment: using regex you can easily solve this.

Comment: you mean store it in a dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy with `split` and `join`:

```
var arr = 'foo.bar.baz'.split('.');
arr.shift() + '[' + arr.join('][') + ']'; // "foo[bar][baz]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't give enough options about edge cases (such as, what if you have a single string, i.e `foo`. Should that return `foo[]` or `foo`?).

Either way here is my shot to this question:

```
function greatFunc(txt) {
    var ls = txt.split('.');
    if (ls.length === 1) {  // edge case here!
        return txt;
    }
    return ls[0] + '[' + ls.splice(1).join('][') + ']';
}

greatFunc('foo.bar.baz') // foo[bar][baz]
greatFunc('foo.bar.baz.kop.pop') // foo[bar][baz][kop][pop]
greatFunc('foo') // foo or foo[] if you delete the if clause.
```

There is of course the regex solution, mention by others! Much cleaner, in my opinion and much faster than any js one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming You are trying to transform the strings that have a '.' before the text.

```
var str = 'foo.bar.baz';
var splittedArray = str.split('.');
var result = splittedArray[0];
for(var i = 1; i < splittedArray.length; i++) {
result += '[' + splittedArray[i] + ']';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex:

```
var str = 'foo.bar.baz';
str = str.replace(/\.([a-z]{3})/g, "[$1]");
```

Comment: I don't think length 3 is a requirement. Consider `/\.([^.]*)/g`

Comment: True. I'm not sure either. ^^